# How do I get these XML values with Linq to XML?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I want a query that will return a IEnumerable of string and inside that have

'as.m3'
'as.m4'

I have tried  `xDoc.Elements("moduleid")` and `xDoc.Descendents("moduleid")`

with no luck

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
<root>
    <code>M11088MUBWWLSRSV9LTJBH81QT</code>
    <moduleid>as.m3</moduleid>
    <moduleid>as.m4</moduleid>
</root>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
xDoc.Descendants("moduleid").Select(x => (string)x);
```

Or:

```
xDoc.Root.Elements("moduleid").Select(x => (string)x);
```